# rsyslog: Forward different message types to same server with different templates

Tags: rsyslog

I have the following rsyslog config:

```
template(name="logz.io" type="string" string="[TOKEN] 
         <%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% [hostname] 
         %app-name% %procid% %msgid%  tag=\"syslog\"] %msg%\n")

# Send messages over TCP using the template.
action(type="omfwd" protocol="tcp" target="listener.logz.io" port="5001"
       template="logz.io" StreamDriver="gtls" StreamDriverMode="1"
       StreamDriverAuthMode="x509/name" StreamDriverPermittedPeers="*.logz.io")
```

Now I would like to have the `type="string"` set according to one of the [message type](http://support.logz.io/hc/en-us/articles/210205985-Which-log-types-are-preconfigured-on-the-Logz-io-platform-). So I could create **individual templates** for each type like

```
template(name="logz.io_nginx" type="nginx" string="[TOKEN] 
         <%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% [hostname] 
         %app-name% %procid% %msgid%  tag=\"nginx\"] %msg%\n")
```

However this means that the action should call the correct template based on the type.

1. How would I configure rsyslog to use the same action with different template?
2. Could I just have one template but for example the `type` parameter dynamically set dependent on the message type?

Answer (score 0):

How is rsyslog supposed to know the message type, which is a logz concept and not an rsyslogd concept?
You will probably have to distinguish the action based on syslogtag/programname, using an if statement, and chose the appropriate template within the if-then-block.